# Usar o tipo JSON do MariaDB é uma boa para guardar chaves primárias?

Tags: banco-de-dados, json, modelagem, mariadb, chave-primária

Estou desenvolvendo um banco de dados para uma agência de viagens local e cheguei num empasse:

Preciso pegar todos os passageiros e armazená-los em uma entidade `Viagem`, de forma que no campo "passageiros" desta última seria do tipo JSON, no qual seria um *array* das chaves estrangeiras dos passageiros.

Exemplo:

```sql
-- Retorna um array de ids de passageiros da última viagem criada.
SELECT passageiros FROM viagens 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 1;

-- retorno
+---------------+
| passageiros   |
+---------------+
| [1,2,3,4,5,6] |
+---------------+
```

A questão é: vocês acham que é uma boa armazenar deste jeito? Afinal, quando precisasse adicionar o id na viagem, basta usar a função `JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE()` do MariaDB, que preservaria os outros *ids*, e adicionaria o próximo no final da lista. E quando eu precisasse pesquisar pelos passageiros da viagem, bastava fazer um algoritmo que pesquisasse pelos *ids* contidos neste *array*.

É uma boa?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

De maneira alguma. Chaves primárias devem ser **estáveis**, se muda não é uma chave primária, este dado claramente é secundário, não sei nem se é adequado acessar assim, mas como chave primária certamente não serve. Então use um `id` ou veja se pode usar alguma outra chave estável.

Não dá para ter certeza, mas parece que nem pode ser garantido que seja único, isso seria um problema maior ainda.

Não é que o banco de dados não aceite, mas conceitualmente está errado usar algo assim. Até poderia usar o JSON, mas usar de uma forma correta quase sempre não fará sentido.

Nem entrei no mérito que isto potencialmente será uma chave muito grande.

Note que eu não disse que sua tabela inteira está errada e deve usar outro modelo (não tenho como se saber se precisa disto sem mais detalhes), falei apenas da chave primária, poder que a tabela esteja ok, pode ser que esta coluna JSON possa ser uma boa para atender sua demanda, desde que ela não seja a chave primária. O mais correto do modelo relacional é criar outra tabela, mas isso nem sempre deve ser a solução mais, a teoria foi criada nos anos 70 quando ninguém pensou ou não tinha recursos computacionais que temos hoje.

Tem algumas perguntas que podem ajudar entender isto:

- [É necessário criar uma chave primária com auto increment?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255270/101)
- [Valores que podem ser inseridos como chave primária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136398/101)
- [Surrogate Key e Natural Key](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277091/101)
- [Gerar a chave primária na aplicação ou mantê-la como auto incrementável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165263/101)
- [Alternativa para CPF (Usuários Estrangeiros)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110641/101)
- [Diferença e utilização entre Primary Key e Foreign Key](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356021/101)
- [Uma chave primária pode ser usada em uma chave estrangeira?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37080/101)
- [É recomendado usar chave primária natural?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28507/101)

Answer (score 1):

O correto é ter uma tabela que faça a relação entre passageiros e viagem, exemplo funcional:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS passageiro(
    _id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS viagem(
    _id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    data_ini DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS viagem_passageiros(
    _id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    viagem_id INT,
    passageiro_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (viagem_id) REFERENCES viagem (_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (passageiro_id) REFERENCES passageiro (_id)
);

insert into passageiro(nome) values ('SemNome1');
insert into passageiro(nome) values ('SemNome2');
insert into passageiro(nome) values ('SemNome3');

insert into viagem(nome,data_ini) values ('Roma', now());

insert into viagem_passageiros(viagem_id, passageiro_id) values (1,1), (1,2), (1,3);
```

Para retorna como uma lista você pode usar:

```
select B.nome, GROUP_CONCAT(C.nome) as passageiros from viagem_passageiros as A
Inner join viagem as B on A.viagem_id = B._id
Inner join passageiro as C on A.passageiro_id = C._id
```

Sqlfinder: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3aeb8/1

> Da pra fazer com Json?

sim você pode criar o campo do tipo Json, 
mas você pode ter muitos problemas futuros, como por exemplo migrar para outro banco de dados que não tenha suporte, manipulação de dados pode se tornar mais complexo, usuário que não existe pode ser adicionado na lista já que não existe uma validação no banco de dados ao menos que vc faca uma função que faca a validação... nada vai ser simples usando essa solução.

Comment: É isso mesmo que vi quando continuei a procurar soluções. Afinal tem uma regra que diz que "se a tabela tiver um campo multivalorado, este vira outra tabela." Obrigado.